# System.InvalidOperationException: 'sequence contains no elements'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, exception

I am trying to login with the help of username and password but it is giving me above error

[image: Login code in C#]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4eVT.png)

Comment: Always add code as text, never image.

Comment: Try to use `SingleOrDefault()` instead of `Single()` in your code.

Comment: Single throws if no user is found for which the filter conditions resolve to true. You also shouldn't persist passwords to the db.

Comment: NEVER store passwords in plain in a database. Use salted hashes instead.

Comment: Could you edit the question, and replace the image with the code in text format?

Answer (score 1):

> Single() returns the only element from a collection, or the only
> element that satisfies the specified condition. If a given collection
> includes no elements or more than one elements then Single() throws
> InvalidOperationException.
>
> SingleOrDefault is just like Single() except that, if no element match the specified condition than it returns default value of underlying type of generic collection. It does not throws InvalidOperationException if no element found. But more than one element found for specified conditions than throws an exception..

So here you can choose to use [SingleOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-8.0) or [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-8.0) method according to your situation.

Comment: Hi @Akash Thakur, Can this answer solved your issue?

Comment: Yes it solved the issue but still its not throwing error when I enter wrong username or password i.e. else condition is not getting executed

Comment: @Akash Thakur, From your code, When user enter wrong username or password, The code will access into `ModelState.AddModelError(xxxxxxx)`, Then the frontend will show this error, Please provide your view code, so that i can check what's going wrong.

Comment: Please check above image for Login View

Comment: Please provide code instead of image, If you just provide image, We can't copy your code to test.

Comment: @Akash Thakur, You can try to write your code like `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "xxxxxxx");`, Then in the view `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`, THen it will show error message successfully.

Comment: @Akash Thakur, Is your project working successfully now?